# Script to wake up and shutdown a remote backup server after rsync command

Tags: ubuntu, backup, rsync, wake-on-lan

How can I script the wake up of a remote backup server (with Ubuntu Server 22.04), and after rsync command is complete, shutdown the server.

For example, the server would turn on every Friday at 12am for the backup with rsync, and after the process was complete, it would be turned off, and would only turn back on again the next Friday.

From what I researched, the action of turning the server on and off can be done with either wol or rtcwake, however, I don't know which would apply better in this case.

Comment: That depends on your hardware and your environment. Just try what is working for you.

Comment: Is it a virtual machine or a psychical server?

Comment: Physicist. I just configured the server to receive wol, through a video I saw on YouTube. My initial script only has the rsync command. I don't know how to turn on the server, nor how to turn it off, if I add something like "shutdown now" in the script, it will turn off my PC, not the server. The server has SSH configured. Ethernet network.